# How to force regex pattern on dictionary values (njsonschema)

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary, jsonschema, njsonschema

Using [njsonschema](https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema), I want to generate a schema that will ensure that all values written to a dictionary will be validated against a regex pattern.

Consider the following class:

```
class File
{
    [RegularExpression("^\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Versions { get; set; }
}
```

The schema part that I wish that njsonschema would generate is:

```
"Versions": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "string",
        "pattern": "^\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$"
    }
}
```

Instaed, njsonschema generates something like this:

```
"Versions": {
  "type": "object",
  "pattern": "^\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "string"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to acheive this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please create an issue on github and reference this question

Comment: Is rhis correctly validated in c#?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed in this commit:

https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/commit/fa1b36b68bb5ad7ec005b2a77002a5668d1aa2b4

A version of NJsonSchema (v9.4.4+) with this fix has been released...